# Bash: Most efficient way to run a command (where the command "might" or "might not" exist prior

Tags: bash, performance

Take the example of pip

We can do

1) Assume command is there and run pip install somepackage. Fail if it gives an exit 1

```
pip install somepackage || exit 1
```

2) Attempt to install pip

```
wget <path online to pip>;   pip install somepackage
```

3) Check pip exists

```
pip --version || wget <path online to pip> &&   pip install somepackage
```

Is there a better way than either of these to check for the existance with the least resource usage

Comment: What are you trying to do? Are you writing a bash script?

Comment: What's inefficient about your current approach? Aside of that I guess it would be better to use `type` to check existence semantically.

Comment: You should assume the command is there; it's the installer's job, not the script's, to ensure the necessary dependencies are in place.

Comment: `pip` may well already be installed, just not someplace your `PATH` knows about, in which case the solution is to adjust the `PATH`, not install `pip` again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if ! type pip;
then
  wget ...
  pip install whatever
fi
```

`type` is a shell builtin that returns true if the command can be found and false otherwise.

Comment: `type` is a bashism. `command -v pip` is the POSIX equivalent (for searching external commands).

Answer (score 2):

Your Python script doesn't have code like

```py
try:
    import requests
except ImportError:
    import subprocess
    subprocess.call(["pip", "install", "requests"])
```

Instead, you have an installer that ensures that `requests` has been installed
before you run your script.

The same logic applies to your shell script. It isn't your script's job to install `pip` if it's missing; whoever runs the script should ensure that `pip` is installed before you run the script. If you do anything, it should simply be to note that `pip` wasn't found.

```sh
if ! command -v pip > /dev/null; then
    printf 'pip not found; check your PATH or install pip before continuing\n' >&2
    exit 1
fi

pip install some package
```